# Prove that every natural number is either even or odd using induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, induction, parity

It is a pretty basic question at first sight. It seems to be intuitively correct but I can't figure out a way to prove it. I think we have to use strong induction but even after sitting on this question for a long time, I still haven't got any leads.

Comment: Do you know the Euclidean division?

Comment: Could you prove if $n$ is even then $n+1$ is odd and vice versa?

Comment: Let $y$ be the smallest integer that is neither even nor odd. Certainly $y \ne 1$. Let $x = y - 1$. Then $y$ is either even or odd. So, by definition, either $y = 2a$ or $y = 2a+1$ for some integer $a$. In each of the two cases, can you reach a contradiction?

Comment: @Michelle I'm not sure it's really legitimate to just quote the division algorithm here... the OP's question is just a special case of the division algorithm for division by $2$, so you are just quoting a theorem (and assuming its proof) to "prove" a subcase.

Comment: @Mathmo123 the question is explicitly asking for a proof using induction, sorry I should have made it clear in the question

Comment: @bonsoir Then, just follow Tanner's hint.

Comment: @bonsoir the proof I gave you is an induction proof in disguise: induction is equivalent to the statement that any non-empty set of integers has a smallest element. To adapt the proof to look like usual induction: $1$ is either even or odd (it's odd). Suppose, for induction, that $k$ is either even or odd. Then, by definition, either $k = 2a$ or $k = 2a+1$ for some integer $a$.  Now prove that $k+1$ is either even or odd.

Comment: Isn't the definition of odd comes from being not even? Seems to me as long as the definition is used every "proof" must be circular.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mathmo123 and J. W. Tanner

Comment: @cr001 usually, one defines a number $n$ to be even if there exists an integer $a$ such that $n = 2a$ and odd if there exists an integer $a$ such that $n = 2a+1$. In principle, one then needs to prove that every number can be written in the form $2a$ or $2a+1$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 The Euclidean division is a very basic tool so understanding it is fundamental for anyone studying math and it naturally leads to an answer of OP's question.

Comment: @Michelle yes it's fundamental... but quoting it in this case leads to reasoning that is essentially circular. Proving Euclidean division works is harder than proving the result the OP is stating.

Comment: @Mathmo123 You're right but I think that the OP will gain much more understanding knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

Define an even number as a multiple of 2, and an odd number as a multiple of 2 plus 1.

Induction. Your inductive hypothesis is $H_n$: the positive integer $n$ is even or odd. $H_1$ is true, because 1 is a multiple of 2 plus 1. Suppose $H_n$ is true. Then either (i) $n$ is a multiple of 2 or (ii) $n$ is a multiple of 2 plus 1. In case (i), $n+1$ is a multiple of 2 plus 1; in case (ii) $n+1$ is a multiple of 2. So in both cases $H_{n+1}$ is true. So $H_n$ is true for all positive integers $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

For positive integer $n$, 
$n$ is odd $\iff 2|(n+1)~$ and 
$n$ is even $\iff 2|n.$

$1$ is odd and $2$ is even.

Inductively assume that $(n+1)$ is odd and $(n+2)$ is even.

Then, $2|([n+1] + 1) \implies 2|([n+3] + 1) \implies (n+3)$ is odd.

Thus, $(n+1)$ is odd $\implies (n+3)$ is odd.

By virtually identical analysis, $(n+2)$ even $\implies (n+4)$ even.

Therefore, you have the base cases of $1$ odd, $2$ even and, by inductive analysis, whenever $(n+1)$ is odd, so is $(n+3)$ and whenever $(n+2)$ is even, so is $(n+4).$

Answer (score 0):

**Base case**: $0$ is even since $0 = 2 \times 0$.

**Assumption**: Assume that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is even or odd. Hence, $n=2k$ or $n=2k+1$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Inductive step**: If $n$ is even, then $n=2k$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Adding one to both sides of the equality, we find that $n+1=2k+1$ (i.e. $n$ is odd). Hence, if $n$ is even, then $n+1$ is odd.* If $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Adding one to both sides of the equality, we find that $n+1=2k+2=2(k+1)$. Since $n+1$ is the product of $2$ and an integer, $n+1$ is even.** Therefore, regardless of whether $n$ is even or odd, $n+1$ is even or odd.

Hence, if the statement is true for $n$, then it is true for $n+1$. Since the statement is true for $n=0$, it must be true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by mathematical induction.

---

*We have actually proven the stronger result that if $n$ is even, then $n+1$ is odd, but this is not strictly necessary for the proof.

**This actually assumes that if $k$ is an integer, then $k+1$ is an integer. This fact is often adopted as an axiom.

Answer (score 0):

The induction proof will be a lot easier to understand if the 'odd' and 'even' aspect is made algebraic from the outset.

*Theorem*

Every natural number is of the form $2k$ or $2k+1$ for some integer $k$.

*Proof*

The first natural number, $1$, is of the form $2\times 0+1$.

Suppose the theorem to be true for the natural number $n$. Then $n$ is either $2k$ or $2k+1$.

Then $n+1$ is either $2k+1$ or $2k+2=2(k+1)$. Hence the theorem is true for the natural number $n+1$.

By induction the theorem is true for all natural numbers.